# Permanently delete DirectWrite from Microsoft Windows

Tags: rendering, font-smoothing, gamma, gdi

I absolutely hate DirectWrite.
[image]

Gamma correction is the most important aspect of font rendering. And GDI passes it perfectly. DirectWrite fails gamma more often than not. That's why reading text in DirectWrite is extremely infuriating. I mean, I don't have eyesight issues that prevent me from reading DirectWrited text, but I absolutely can't help but to notice incorrect gamma and I despise any incorrect gamma text.

I don't use the latest versions of Mozilla Firefox and Chromium as the text rendering is a dealbreaker.

I'm looking for a way to permanently delete DirectWrite from Windows 10.

Edit: Here's a comparison showing renderings of both ClearType OFF and ClearType ON, both GDI and DirectWrite, both light theme and dark theme, and arrows indicating the square that directly influences the gamma correction in the light and dark themes:
[image]

Comment: Its probably me, but I think the DirectWrite one looks way better... I would not disable it. But yeah, that's why this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It's in your opinion. In my opinion the DirectWrite sample looks absolutely horrible and unsmooth, and it's technically true as the gamma test fails. DirectWrite feels very cursed to me.

Comment: Short answer, No you cannot, it can be disabled in some Browsers though.

Comment: Removing DirectWrite from your operating system would require modifying Windows DLLs and that is a major undertaking. The next best thing you can do is tweak settings for your OS and specific programs to avoid using DirectWrite, but even some applications can still use it with GDI in software rendering mode.

Answer (score 0):

GDI is used when hardware acceleration is not available.  Individual applications might use GDI if they have an option to disable hardware acceleration.

Try telling Windows to not use hardware acceleration folllwing [this](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/hardware-acceleration-windows-7).

You can also uninstall your display adapter drivers and use the default VGA 800x600 which doesn't support graphic acceleration of any kind.

Comment: DirectWrite [can still be used with GDI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/rendering-directwrite), so this may not disable DirectWrite for *every* application.